# Selecting collection view cell programmatically cannot do some of the cell's isSelected routines

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code to change the color and font style of a cell when it is selected. It worked except that when I select it manually from the parent view's `init(frame:)` function. It supposed to change the color to blue and font style to bold and it worked perfectly when I toggled it from the test device. However, when I tried to set the default selected item programmatically, it only changed the style to bold but the color is still the same as unselected, ie. gray.

This is the cell's class:

```
class ItemCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setupCell(title: String)
    {
        titleLabel.text = title
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
    }


    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet {
            titleLabel.textColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.gray
            titleLabel.font = isSelected ? UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: titleLabel.font.pointSize) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: titleLabel.font.pointSize)
        }
    }

}
```

The parent view that has the collection view in it:

```
class ItemsView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    let reuseableCellId = "itemCell"

    let nibItemCell = UINib(nibName: "ItemCollectionCell", bundle: nil)


    //Collection view for items
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        //Create subview (collection) for the menu buttons
        //Register cell's XIB and class
        cv.register(nibItemCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseableCellId)
        //Set subview BG color
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cv.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //Add subview
        self.addSubview(collectionView)

        //Set subview constraints
        self.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        self.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)

        let selectedPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
    }

    //... all the other funcs
}
```

What went wrong here? How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After meddling with the code myself, I found out that the `setupCell(title:)` function is the culprit. FYI, the setupCell is called in the `cellForItemAt()` delegate function. And when I moved the `titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray` line to `awakeFromNib()` it works fine now. Thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the collectionview is reloaded prior to selecting the cell. Plus, have you tried manually updating isSelected?

Comment: After meddling with the code myself, I found out that the `setupCell(title:)` function is the culprit. FYI, the setupCell is called in the `cellForItemAt()` delegate function. And when I moved the `titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray` line to `awakeFromNib()` it works fine now. Thanks anyway.